# NodeJS Request, Wait for java-script injected content

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i am trying to get a entire page contents. The issue im having is that on the particular page is the following code:

```
<div class="line-item" data-get-url="/currency/line-items/378303049" 
style="display: none;">
```

This content appears to be javascript injected, How do i make request wait for the content to be injected?

Thank you to anyone that can help me with this.

Current code:

```
var url = 'https://www.daniel.com/my/groupadmin.aspx?gid=' + groupId + 
'#nav-revenue';
var headers = { 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3712.0 Safari/537.36',
'Cookie': cookieString,
'Referer': 'https://www.daniel.com/groups/' + groupId
};

request.post({ url: url, headers: headers, followAllRedirects: true }, function (e, r, body) {


var mystr = body;
//console.log(body);
//Splitting it with : as the separator
   var myarr = mystr.split('<div class="summary" data-get-url="/currency/summary/');

var myvar = myarr[1];

var token = myvar.split('">');

var tokenbody = token[0];

   console.log(mystr);
   console.log(tokenbody); // "nu"
});
```

## UPDATE

With about 4 headaches, 5 energy drinks, 1 cup of coffee and a broken monitor i have finally managed to resolve my problem. I have swapped from using request and im now using unirest. With unirest i can make the first request to the site, then a second while keeping logged in and the headers set. Thanks to anyone who helped and responded. Goodluck to anyone else that needs to do this! I wish you all the very best!

Comment: Hi Daniel, May I ask what do you mean with `How do i make request wait for the content to be injected?`. I couldn't understand the question..

Comment: Hey, im really sorry about the confusing question. Basically that current code doesn't load all the content.When i dig deeper the data-get-url="/currency/line-items/378303049" bit isnt getting loaded. How do i make request load all of the content? Thank you so much for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped to using unirest instead so i could hold the connection and then make another redirect to the content i needed.